# Trying to add Firebase to Android Studio Project, but It Will not Add (app:processDebugGoogleServices Error)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-play-services

I have been trying to add Firebase to my android studio project, but I keep running into the following error when I sync w/ gradle:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonArray
```

Here are my two gradle files:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()

    }
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.platin.helpstl2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23

        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.6"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'

    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The only time I can successfully sync w/ gradle is when I remove both         `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` and  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`  so I am assuming the error is with one of those two.  I have already followed the instructios on Firebase's website, but I am having no luck.

Quick update: it actually seems as if the error is now emitting from the google-services json file because the debug error occurs after this line: `Parsing json file: C:\Users\toshiba\AndroidStudioProjects\HelpSTL\app\google-services.json`

Thanks for any help,

Jacob

Comment: @Shubhank 2.2 Preview 2

Comment: First you integrate google plus in your project and clean and rebuild your project. i hope. i will be work... you missing google-services.json . which is used to google plus integration in project....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I actually solved the problem on my own; the problem was with the google-services.json file that you need from firebase.  I just redownloaded and installed that file and it now works!